# Check in the receiver if the service is running

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I made an app that use the Android Cloud to Device Messaging and since I use this app starting it from the proper icons it works fine. The problem I found is after the boot of the device itself. After the boot the receiver starts correctly and correctly starts the service that I want to use, checking it if it's running to do some tasks and eventually launch another service.

To achieve it I did this:

on the manifest:

```
         <receiver android:name=".C2DMReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">             
          <!-- Receive the actual message -->
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
              <category android:name="com.myapp.app" />
          </intent-filter>
          <!-- Receive the registration id -->
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
              <category android:name="com.myapp.app" />
          </intent-filter>
                 <intent-filter>
                <action   android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <category android:name="com.myapp.app" />
            </intent-filter> 
     </receiver>
```

In my receiver:

```
        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {

        Intent NewIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.startService(NewIntent);
        Log.i("C2DMReceiver", "MyService started");
    }
```

Then onMessage receive the receiver must check if MyService is running. To do that I write this inside MyService:

```
    // Use activity in C2DMReceiver class
public static Service getCurrentService() {
    return curService;
}
```

So to check in the receiver I do this:

```
if (MyService.getCurrentService != null){
        //DO ELSE
    }
```

The problem is that always this boolean condition is false, even if the service is really running.

Why?

Comment: Are you giving a value to curService? As in `curService = this;`?

Comment: Yes sir, in MyService I added this:private static Service curService = null and onCrete curService=MyService.this

Comment: Shouldn't `MyService.getCurrentService` be `MyService.getCurrentService()`?

Comment: Yes sir, correct, just did a mistake here writing the code, sorry, but it's correct in the app.

Comment: try moving the `curService=MyService.this` to your onStartCommand or onStart method, whichever one you're using.

Comment: Is your `Service` or `BroadcastReceiver` running in another process? Please post the manifest entries for your `Service` and your `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: Don't you forget boot completed permission? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>